# MySQL-Python Wont create the table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to create a few tables using Python, the first few worked and this specific one not.
This is my code:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE citizens(\
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,\
    full_name VARCHAR(100),\
    age INT,\
    Gender ENUM('F', 'M'),\
    cultivation VARCHAR(100),\
    rank INT,\
    isRouge ENUM('Yes', 'No'),\
    sect_id INT)"

mycursor.execute(sql)
```

and this is the error it gives me:

```
MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
 near 'rank INT,    isRouge ENUM('Yes', 'No'),    sect_id INT)' at line 1
```

what is it thaat I am missing?

Comment: Your error may be caused by using a MySQL reserved word as `rank`.

Comment: @lemon, Thanks ! man idk how i didnt notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"rank" bad field name. This is a reserved word
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: indeed it's working good now ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Why this happens

Problem here is `rank` is a reserved keyword, as in @DSKalugin 's answer. Change it to other name like `my_rank` will resolve this.

### An extra tip

In addition. using [triple quoted strings](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#2to3:%7E:text=triple%2Dquoted%20string) is an easier way for multi-line string.

> Python's triple quotes comes to the rescue by allowing strings to span multiple lines, including verbatim NEWLINEs, TABs, and any other special characters.

from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/triple-quotes-in-python/

So a more readable way is like:

```py
sql_request = """
    CREATE TABLE citizens(
        ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        full_name VARCHAR(100),
        age INT,
        Gender ENUM('F', 'M'),
        cultivation VARCHAR(100),
        my_rank INT,
        isRouge ENUM('Yes', 'No'),
        sect_id INT)
    """
```

### TL;DR

When reviewing First Answers, Stack Overflow cannot accept my edit, saying "The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!"

I came here and saw the correct answer was already here.
I post my edited version of @Sem Lion 's answer here anyway in case if it helps.